# Reverse the data stack using loops

Tags: forth, gforth

I'm trying to reverse the stack using two loops one to send items from the data stack to return stack. And another to get them from return stack to data stack.
Unfortunately, it doesn't work & gforth returns the stack underflow error.
Below is the code:

```
: srev ( n n2 n3 n4 n5 -- n5 n4 n3 n2 n)
 6 0 do >r loop 
 6 0 do r> loop ;

1 2 3 4 5 srev
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The trouble you've got here is that `DO ... LOOP` keeps the loop parameters (index and termination value) on the return stack and discards them at the end of the loop. That's why `>R` and `R>` *must* be in balanced pairs during a loop.

Your code puts a value on the return stack during the loop, which then gets discarded at the end of the loop, leaving a stray loop parameter still there and the whole thing goes haywire.

You can get the result you want like this ...

```
: REVERSE ( i*x i -- i*y ) 0 DO I ROLL LOOP ;
```

... though I'm a bit puzzled as to why you'd want to!

EDIT (after reading comments and ruvim's reply):

1. Your initial reversing the stack algorithm wouldn't have worked anyway, as a series of `R>`s reverses the order onto the return stack, and the corresponding `>R`s
   reverses it again back to the parameter stack leaving the order as it was.
2. Alternative approach, similar to ruvim's but without recursion, is here

```
    : APPLY ( n*x xt n -- n*x' )
        DUP 1- -ROT                ( n*x n-1 xt n )
        0 DO                       ( n*x n-1 xt )
           2>R                     \ park n-1 xt on return stack 
           2R@ DROP ROLL           \ bring next item to top
           2R@ NIP EXECUTE         \ apply the function to it
           2R>                     \ clear junk off return stack for now
        LOOP                       ( n*x n-1 xt )
        2DROP
    ;
```

It won't work (because of using `ROLL`) with anything that affects the stack depth like `DROP` or `DUP`, but `' 2* 4 APPLY` works just fine!

Comment: Thanks! It makes sense. The way i was solving some problems there were some numbers on the stack. 1 2 3 4 5 . Now i needed to perform some operation let's say x on each one of them. Using the return stack and two loops appered to be a good approach. so, i was aiming for  : f 6 0 do 2* >r loop 6 0 do r> loop  ;   which should've worked for it.

Comment: After working with your example for a bit. Tried 2* after roll. It works, just stack may need another reverse operation when order needs preservation.

Answer (score 4):

There is no need to reverse N top stack items to [apply some operation](/questions/60014491/reverse-the-data-stack-using-loops#comment106140670_60015133) for each of them. A possible solution is the following.

```
: apply-top ( i*x u.i xt -- j*x ) \ xt ( x -- k*x )
  swap dup 0= if 2drop exit then ( ... x xt u.i )
  rot >r 1- swap dup >r recurse ( R: x xt )
  2r> execute
;
```

This word removes the arguments from the data stack and then applies *xt* to each *x* from *i*x*, starting with the bottom one and ending with the top one.

Usage examples:

```
2 3 4  3 ' 2* apply-top ( 4 6 8 ) . . .  \ it prints "8 6 4 "
2 3 4  3 ' drop apply-top ( ) \ it just drops 3 top items
2 3    2 ' dup apply-top ( 2 2 3 3 ) \ it duplicates each item
```

Comment: Thanks! It solves the problem i mentioned in comments effectively. I tried refactoring by removing swap and count i and, integrate depth 1- but i start to get stackoverflow. Even though it should have worked the same. : a3 depth 1- dup 0= if 2drop exit then rot >r 1- swap dup >r recurse 2r> execute ; 2 3 4 ' 2* a3

Comment: `: a3 ( i*x xt -- j*x ) depth 1 = if drop exit then swap >r dup >r recurse 2r> execute ;`